# Why to use @PropertySource instead of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-config

In `Spring` **Javadoc**:

> "existing configuration makes use of the "systemPropertiesMode" and/or
>   "systemPropertiesModeName" properties. Users are encouraged to move
>   away from using these settings, and rather configure property source
>   search order through the container's Environment"

Why is it encouraged to search through container's Environment?

EDIT:

Need to understand why to use @PropertySource instead of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, what benefits does PropertySource gives over PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer if both achieve the goals of fetching resources mentioned through the path.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is because rule [#3 of 12 factor app principles](https://12factor.net/config):

> The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables (often shortened to env vars or env). Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config files, or other config mechanisms such as Java System Properties, they are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.